# Javascript chrome extension to click all elements on the page only updating half

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a simple extension to click all the buttons on a web page that have the same element name, however, when I print the console log without the "updateArray[a].click()" it prints the correct array length. But when I add the "updateArray[a].click()" back it only click half the array length which is weird. How is it that when I add that line back it only clicks half of the button on the elements page, also when i add that line back my array length cuts in half?

```
function clickUpdate() {
    var updateArray = document.getElementsByClassName("updateButton");

     for(var a=0;a<updateArray.length;a++){ 
     updateArray[a].click(); 
     console.log("this is the array:" + a);
}
console.log("this is the array legnth: " + updateArray.length);
}
clickUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does the result of `updateArray[a].click();` remove the `updateButton` class from the element? because `updateArray` is not actually an array, it's a HTMLCollection, which will change if you remove that class from any of it's elements ... i.e. if you remove the class `updateButton` from any of the elements in that collection, that collection will shrink by 1 member - which is why you end up clicking only half the elements

I suggest using something like this

```
function clickUpdate() {
    var updateArray = document.getElementsByClassName("updateButton");
    [].slice.call(updateArray).forEach(function(item) {
        item.click();
    });
    console.log("this is the array legnth: " + updateArray.length);
}
clickUpdate();
```

this uses the array#slice function to create a (static) copy of the data in updateArray, then uses forEach on this new array to do the clicking

alternatively, if you use `querySelectorAll` what you end up with is a `NodeList` - which isn't a "live" list like an `HTMLCollection` you get with `getElementsByClassName

```
function clickUpdate() {
    var updateArray = document.querySelectorAll(".updateButton");

     for(var a=0;a<updateArray.length;a++){ 
     updateArray[a].click(); 
     console.log("this is the array:" + a);
}
console.log("this is the array legnth: " + updateArray.length);
}
clickUpdate();
```

Comment: Oh okay, that makes a lot more sense, I am still new to this so I thought the arrays in HTML work in a similar fashion as in other languages. So when you call "[].slice.call(updateArray)" this makes a copy of the array in a new array?

Comment: `arrays in HTML` - no such thing ... arrays in javascipt work just like arrays should ... HTMLCollection is "array like" but not an array

Comment: `this makes a copy of the array in a new array` - more or less, yes - see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)